# automate Chart with Selenium, extract content by mouseover/hover across chart

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

```
<div class="chart-hover-tip" style="display: none; left: ***442.289***px; top: 81.3333px; opacity: 1;">
<table class="ng-scope" cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="chart-tip-head">
        <tr class="time-info">
            <td colspan="2">
                <i class="icon-globe"></i>
                <span class="label ng-binding">
                       **Wed, Mar 12**
                </span>
                <span class="label ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="timezoneLabel" style="display: block; padding-left: 22px;">
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="chart-tip-body”<!ngRepeat: legend in legends>
<td class="value">
       <b once-text="legend.point[1]|rankfmt" style="text-align: right;">
          **10**
```

There is a chart in the webpage that displays some content (the date in class time-info and value in chart-tip-body) dynamically as one hovers over the chart (as the pixels change in class chart-hover-tip "style left:"). With Selenium, I want to simulate moving over a range of coordinates to retrieve different content -the date and its corresponding value. How can I do this using Selenium, I am not sure how to start since this involves changing the pixels in the CSS? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the size and location of the element and simulated movements over the chart with the mouse over a range of coordinates using ActionChains. The relevant methods to use from ActionChains are: move_to_element and move_to_element_with_offset

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use co-ordinates in order to retrieve content from a portal.

What you can do is this:

Create a method with a WebElement return type, and use the Method findElement(). Example:

```
WebDriver test;
test = new FirefoxDriver();

public static WebElement checkAndGet(By b) throws Exception {
return test.findElement(b);
}
```

Store the WebElement and use the Method getText(). Example:

```
WebElement date = checkAndGet(By.xpath("//span[@class='label ng-binding']");
date.getText();
```

Then you can print it or do whatever you want. Example:

```
System.out.println(date.getText());
```

Hope this helps!